# Highchart piechart colour fade for smaller slices

Tags: highcharts, colors, pie-chart, fade

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr2lP.png)
Hi i have this highchart which displays a lot of data as the slices get smaller the chart color fades how can i avoid this without the need to reduce the number of data being displayed

i tried to incre0

I want the chart to be something like this without the fading/whitespaces on smaller slicesase the minSize property of the chart but nothing works [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g93ql.png)

Comment: Are you looking for the `borderWidth` option? Here is the example demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q5gahwep/

Comment: if you increase the size to 900. you can still see that faded area/ whitespace on the chart

Comment: I get you, I prepared the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

dont want to delete the response thread

Comment: Hi, please edit your question instead of putting your requirements in the answer ;) thanks in advance!

Comment: @magdalena i cannot find the option to edit a post. that aside can you please provide a solution for the issue?

Comment: The Edit link is available under the post, alongside the Share|Edit|Follow|Flag options. Additionally, for future reference, please include example code.

Comment: @magdalena  you can use the demo project and increase the number of records in the chart and you begin to see this fading/witespace where smaller slices should be: https://codepen.io/jjpo/pen/dyaGbyy

Comment: hi @magdalena is there a way to fix this in highchart. i am working on an enterprise application

Answer (score 0):

**According to the API:**

*When setting the border width to 0, there may be small gaps between the slices due to SVG antialiasing artefacts. To work around this, keep the border width at 0.5 or 1, but set the borderColor to null instead.*

**Code:**

```
series: [{
    borderColor: null,
    borderWidth: 1,
    data
}]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x1tsezan/

**API Refernce:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.borderWidth